# JSON.parse() cannot parse to JSON correctly in cloud code

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a cloud code job that is supposed to start an httpRequest and store the JSON received in a class. So far the JSON is returned from the httpResponse but `JSON.parse()` does not seem to work correctly. This is a part of my cloud code job:

```js
var str = httpResponse.text;
console.log("news " + str);
var jsonNews = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(jsonNews);
```

Here are my logs:
After `console.log("news " + str);` I have this:

```
news {"name":"News","count":71,"frequency":"Daily","version":3,
"newdata":true,"lastrunstatus":"success","thisversionstatus":"success",
"nextrun":"Wed Dec 23 2015 17:52:28 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
"thisversionrun":"Tue Dec 22 2015 17:52:28 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
"results":{"collection1":[{"date":"Dec-22:","headline":
{"href":"http://ghanafa.org/pages/gfa/201512/11174.php",
"text":"GFA holds Media & Marketing for Premier/... (truncated)
```

and after `console.log(jsonNews);` I have:

```
{"name":"News","count":71,"frequency":"Daily","version":3,
"newdata":true,"lastrunstatus":"success","thisversionstatus":"success",
"nextrun":"Wed Dec 23 2015 17:52:28 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
"thisversionrun":"Tue Dec 22 2015 17:52:28 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
"results":{"collection1":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],"collection2":[{}]}}
```

Why am I losing data in my JSON object? Is it really JSON.parse() in cloud code that causes the problem? If so, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Are you sure you're losing data? Maybe `console.log` truncates below a certain depth. Try `console.log(jsonNews.results.collection1[0])`. (It's a stretch, I'll admit.)

Comment: if you're using Firebug you could probably click on those Object Literals within those Arrays and look deeper to see if there's a problem at all.

Comment: It could be the JSON string is incorrectly formatted. Try to copy/paste the entire string into a JSON formatter/beautifier/validator/etc. [such as this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com).

Comment: Use curl to call the cloud code. Store to file . Open file in editor and dump it into a json verifyer